# Ubuntu Server lts installation fails at curtin command in-target

Tags: server

I'm trying to install the Ubuntu Server lts on a computer, but the process always fails at curtin command in-target. The program gives me the option to "View error report", but that just restarts the intalation process without showing me anything, and the "Reboot now" option doesen't help either, it just loads forever. The computer already had Windows installed, but the installer should have wiped the drive clean. What should I do?

Edit for more info:

This error occurs in the last step of the instalation, after "configuring apt" appears on the command window. The process stops at "curtin command in-target", and a message appears on top of the screen telling me "An error occured during instalation". I couldn't find any error logs, most likely because I'm very inexperienced with Linux overall. I'm also installing through a USB stick.

Comment: Any more information on the error? In what step does it occur? Are you past the network setup, the disc layout, the hostname & username setup? Does it give any other error information?